# The correct sytax for IF THEN with variables

Tags: java, android

How does one code for a choice between two options?

```
if ((one_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()
                    .equals("one"))) {
                double one_thing = new Double(one.getText()
                        .toString());
                double two_thing = one_thing * 5;

            } else {
                double two_thing = new Double(one.getText()
                        .toString());
                double one_thing = two / 5;
            }
```

Comment: This seems correct. So what is the problem?

Comment: @Tudor: Presumably that the scope of the variables is limited to inside the if-else blocks.

Comment: I think they are concerned that one_spinner can only be "one" or "two", and an `else` doesn't fully enforce this.  But I'm not sure I'm understanding this vague question either.

Comment: I suspect your question isn't the one you're asking.

Comment: java/eclipse wanted me to rename one_thing and two_thing in the IF because it was already defined in the ELSE?  I got the answer from Jon Skeet and and have been happily coding since this morning.  The question got closed before I had any chance of editting and making the question better.  I still would like to thank everyone to data because I have learned a lot from Stack Exchange and I started with no knowledge of java or android xml and I almost have a complete app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to refer to `one_thing` and `two_thing` *after* the `if` statement, you need to declare them before the `if` statement, so that they'll still be in scope:

```
double one_thing;
double two_thing;
if (one_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("one")) {
   one_thing = Double.parseDouble(one.getText().toString());
   two_thing = one_thing * 5;
} else {
   two_thing = Double.parseDouble(one.getText().toString());
   one_thing = two_thing / 5;
}
```

Note that this can be simplified in terms of removing redundant code:

```
double parsedValue = Double.parseDouble(one.getText().toString());

double one_thing;
double two_thing;
if (one_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("one")) {
   one_thing = parsedValue;
   two_thing = one_thing * 5;
} else {
   two_thing = parsedValue;
   one_thing = two_thing / 5;
}
```

Or, given that the relationship between the two is always a factor of 5:

```
double one_thing = Double.parseDouble(one.getText().toString());
if (one_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("one")) {
   one_thing = one_thing / 5;
}
double two_thing = one_thing * 5;
```

Note that conventionally these names would be `oneThing` and `twoThing`, by the way.

Comment: Jon - Thank-you for your answer,  I am a real novice with java (self taught) and I find it hard to read variables without the 'underscore' but always willing to learn so i did use the convention this time and will force myself to change.  I am trying to parse about ten variables that can be shown as either english or metric and then convert to metric or english and know both values.

Comment: Thanks again, I learned about scope a while back.  How that I have an understanding of some java, what kind of cources should I take to get a better understanding.  I like that I understand some and think I would be a really good student.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use the conditional operator:

```
double a = condition ? option1 : option2;
double b = condition ? option3 : option4;
```

Comment: How is that going to assign values to two different variables?